# Hibernate Search - Wildcard and space

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate Search with multiple words/fields and it works as expected until I enable Wildcards.
This is my Entity Analyzer:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "autocompleteAnalyzer",
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
                // remove accents
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class),
                // lower case
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                // Start with same root
                @TokenFilterDef(
                        factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class,
                        params = { @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English") })
        })
```

And this is my query:

```java
    if(criteria.length() > 0) {
        fullTextQuery = queryBuilder
                .keyword()
                // .wildcard() => not in use 
                .onFields("firstName", "lastName", "extraName", "biography")
                .matching(criteria)
                .createQuery();
```

**Scenario 01**
If I search for something like "John Smith", I do get the following query out:

```
+((firstName:john firstName:smith) 
(lastName:john lastName:smith) 
(extraName:john extraName:smith) 
(biography:john biography:smith))
```

Which finds anybody named John or Smith.

**Scenario 02**
If I search for "John*", because I want to find anybody where the name start with John (Johnny, Johson) I need to enable wildcards as following:

```
fullTextQuery = queryBuilder
   .keyword()
   .wildcard()
```

Which works when I type "John*" by returning the following query:

```
+(firstName:john* lastName:john* extraName:john* biography:john*)
```

But it doesn't work anymore when I type something like "John* Smith" because it doesn't split the words, which I believe is due to the Wildcard option:

```
+(firstName:john* smith lastName:john* smith extraName:john* smith biography:john* smith)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword queries will always match documents that contain any of the provided keywords. Wildcard queries do not apply analysis. So neither is a good fit in your case.

Use a simpleQueryString query, and force the default operator to "and":

```
        fullTextQuery = queryBuilder
                .simpleQueryString()
                .onFields("firstName", "lastName", "extraName", "biography")
                .withAndAsDefaultOperator()
                .matching(criteria)
                .createQuery();
```

Documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_simple_query_string_queries

Comment: It's not and "and" between fields, it's an and between keywords. Please try it?

Comment: Apologize, actually I was missing the *. It works as expected.